# in rails i need to get all records based on a date range, ignoring the year

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i am trying to get all records within a date range in rails that fall after a given start date and before a given end date, ignoring the year. the start date will just be a month. the end of the date range is a month and date.
the following example is to get users with a hire date month equal to january or greater, but less than 2(february) / 28(day).
i was trying this but it doesnt work:

```
users.where('extract(month from hire_date) >= ?', 1).where('extract(month from hire_date) <= ? AND extract(day from hire_date) <= ?', 2, 28)
```

the reason this doesnt work is it will exclude users, for example who fall on 1/29, because their day in january is not less than 28.

is there a good way to make this work, ignoring the year on the date field?

Comment: Just to be clear, it sounds like you are checking for any hire dates in January or February with the exception of February 29?

Comment: im trying to get hire dates, essentially, after 1 january but before 2/28, regardless of the year. so from 1/1 up until 2/28. these dates are being dynamically calculated based on some parameters of an associated model.

Comment: Your answer is only further confusing matters.  “after 1 January but before 2/28” = 01/02-02/27 whereas some of your other statements seem to indicate that 01/01 and 02/28 should be included.  In addition, you failed to confirm that 02/29 should indeed be excluded.  If the year is going to be ignored then it seems a little odd that the last day of February every 4 years would be considered out of the range.

Comment: sorry. what im going for is hire date with month 1 through and including 2/28. i misquoted my code when i was writing it out in english. (from 1/1 up to and including 2/28), these start and end dates can change every time a model the dates are derived from are created and this operation is performed upon the dates provided by when the new model is created. im just using 2/28 as an example. so in the future, the range could be from and including 3/1 up to and including 6/15.

Comment: Copy.  Thanks for the clarification.  I think your question should probably be edited to include a more generic range because my initial view and instinct is to just test against January and February based on your provided example.

Comment: Followup question:  Will the range always land inside a calendar year or could it possibly start in December and then run through January?

Comment: Ahh sorry. It could span two calendar years, example, December 1 to and including January 12.

Comment: OK. Last question:  could the first or last day of the range ever equal February 29?

Comment: I suppose it could yes. The date is coming from an adjoining record that an admin can create and I’m basically getting the ending date by doing ending_date = adjoining_record.created_at + 30.days. So if they created the adjoining record on January 29th and it was a leap year, the end of the date range would then be 2/29.

Comment: OK. That was some helpful information. I think there are much easier ways to do what you are trying to do.  I would suggest adding the information about how you are arriving at the end date to your question.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! I’ll add in the other bits of code that you suggested into my question tomorrow when I’m at my computer.

Comment: What is the data type of `hire_date` in the database and what database do you use?

Comment: @spickermann, hire_date is type 'date' and im using postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to transform the dates into strings including just the month and the day. For example `2021-12-31` could be translated into `"12-31"`. That string can then be compared to the range of date strings you are interested in.

```
users.where("to_char(hire_date, 'MM-DD') BETWEEN '01-01' AND '02-29'")
```

Note that this, in theory, this would also match invalid date strings like '01-40'. But I guess it is safe to assume that `to_char` with a valid date will never return such invalid date strings.

Comment: this works great! i worked out something similar using extract month and day and turning them into an integer, but this is less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I'm not familiar with `ruby-on-rails`, `sql`, or `activerecord` but this question really piqued my interest because it contains a number of complexities that I've never had to deal with.  Most notably:

- How to accommodate leap years when the test range and target date may
  have differing leap year statuses.
- How to deal with a hire date of February 29th.  This may seem to be
  the same as the first item on my list, but it has its own unique
  nuances.
- How to deal with ranges that started in one year and then overlap into the next.

I did some searching myself and there seems to be very little information out there on the subject, particularly any that seems to properly deal with the various complexities listed above, so I decided to see if I could come up with a logical approach of my own.  It seems like it may be a novel approach, but ultimately I decided that converting `month` and `day` to `float` values would allow an easy way to address the leap year issue as well as the issue with February 29th, and that testing the date ranges using an `if/else` statement along with opposing boolean operations would solve the ranges that overlap years.

You may have to extrapolate and reconfigure for your specific needs, but here's the general idea written out in pure `ruby`.  It's rather verbose, but I did so just to try and make it more clear what I'm doing.  I could be made much more compact:

```
hire_date = Time.new(2004, 1, 22)

provided_start_date = Time.new(2008, 12, 22)

day_value = (60*60*24)  #60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours = 1 day
num_days = 30

calculated_end_date =  provided_start_date + num_days*day_value

start_range = provided_start_date.month + provided_start_date.day/100.0
end_range = calculated_end_date.month + calculated_end_date.day/100.0
day_float = hire_date.month + hire_date.day/100.0

if start_range < end_range
  result = day_float >= start_range and day_float <= end_range
else
  result = day_float >= start_range or day_float <= end_range
end

result
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out something that worked for this.
given the following:

```
start_date = 01 Jan 2021
end_date = 02 Feb 2021

Users.where("(extract(month from hire_date) * 100 + extract(day from hire_date)) BETWEEN ? AND ?", ((start_date.month * 100) + start_date.day), ((end_date.month * 100) + end_date.day))
```

start date and end date can be any dates and this should work to get all users between, since SQL between is inclusive, it will also get users whos end and start dates fall on the start / end date, ignoring year.